# Does react re-render components that don't depend on state when the state changes?

Tags: reactjs

The `StateIndependentComponent` is a heavy component and `StateDependentComponent` is light but the state changes multiple times and quickly.

So, will `StateIndependentComponent` be re-rendered every time the state changes?

```
<StateIndependentComponenet />
<StateDependentComponent data={this.state.data} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you implemented your components. By default yes, but you can use [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) (class components) or [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (function components) to make the component only rerender when it's props or state actually change.

```
class StateIndependentComponenet extends React.PureComponent {
    ...
}
```

or

```
const StateIndependentComponenet = React.memo((props) => {
    ...
})
```

Be sure to care about the note that is in the React docs linked above, because your component will not rerender seemingly randomly if you are mutating state by accident.